# How to use a value from another property in the same yaml file?

Tags: spring, variables, properties, yaml, config

I have property file application-dev.yml with content:

```
spring.profiles: dev
config:
    value: test
    property: test2
foo:
    value: test
    property: test2
bar:
    value: test
    property: test2
```

There are some redundant values to my properties and in case I ever want to change `test` to `blah` and `test2` to `blah2`, I would have to go to every instance of the text and change it.

Is there some way I can (in Java terms) declare a variable and assign it to `test' and just use the variable throughout my yaml file so that I consolidate the text and make it easier to change in the future if needed?

Answer (score 7):

YAML does have anchors and aliases, which allow you to identify a certain value by giving it an anchor, and later reference it again with an alias:

```yaml
spring.profiles: dev
config:
    value: &a test
    property: &b test2
foo:
    value: *a
    property: *b
bar:
    value: *a
    property: *b
```

Mind that this is not the same as a variable. YAML serializes a node graph, which is in its most common form, i.e. without using anchors/aliases, a tree structure. You can use anchors & aliases to serialize any directed graph structure, including cyclic graphs. This is what the feature is for.

The difference to a variable is that you do not have a *definition* of the value – instead, you add the anchor to the first occurrence of the value. You can then reference it in subsequent occurrences. Other differences include that you cannot *process* the value in any way, e.g. via string concatenation or interpolation. For example, if you want some key to have the value `testtest2`, you cannot express that via the aliases `*a` and `*b`.